# Beginner CUDA - Simple var increment not working

Tags: c++, cuda

I am working on a project with CUDA. To get the hang of it, I have the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

__global__ void inc(int *foo) {
  ++(*foo);
}

int main() {
  int count = 0, *cuda_count;
  cudaMalloc((void**)&cuda_count, sizeof(int));
  cudaMemcpy(cuda_count, &count, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cout << "count: " << count << '\n';
  inc <<< 100, 25 >>> (&count);
  cudaMemcpy(&count, cuda_count, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaFree(cuda_count);
  cout << "count: " << count << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Output is

```
count: 0
count: 0
```

What's the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should probably work through some of the examples in the programming guide. Your syntax has discrepancies from what is suggested in the programming guide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution. I just had to use an atomic function, i.e a function that is executed without interference from other threads. 
In other words, no other thread can access a specific address until the operation is 
complete.

*Code:*

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

__global__ void inc(int *foo) {
  atomicAdd(foo, 1);
}

int main() {
  int count = 0, *cuda_count;
  cudaMalloc((void**)&cuda_count, sizeof(int));
  cudaMemcpy(cuda_count, &count, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cout << "count: " << count << '\n';
  inc <<< 100, 25 >>> (cuda_count);
  cudaMemcpy(&count, cuda_count, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaFree(cuda_count);
  cout << "count: " << count << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

*Output:*

```
count: 0
count: 2500
```

Thank you for making me realize the error that I was committing.

Answer (score 8):

You should pass `cuda_count` to your kernel function. Apart from that, all your threads are trying to increment the same memory location. The effect of that isn’t well-defined (at least one write will succeed, but more than one can).

You need to prevent that by only letting one thread perform the work:

```
__global__ void inc(int *foo) {
  if (blockIdx.x == 0 && threadIdx.x == 0)
    ++*foo;
}
```

(untested)

Comment: What a failure of mine. Yet, the output it's still wrong. It gives me 1 instead the expected 2500.

Comment: @Renato: this isn’t how CUDA works. See my updated answer: it’s simply undefined to write to the same memory location from different threads. What you want is a so-called gather operation. Implementing this isn’t trivial.

Comment: Konrad's fix ensures that only threads with `threadIdx.x == 0` will attempt to increment the variable, but since you are launching many blocks you will have many threads with that index. Try `blockIdx.x == 0 && threadIdx.x == 0`. Having said that, it may be worth checking out some of the SDK samples for a clearer idea of how this all works...

Comment: @Tom: Thanks, I’ve changed my answer accordingly. It’s been two years since I last used CUDA.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you're passing to the device kernel pointer to pointer to count. Not pointer to count. One '&' too much

This line

```
inc <<< 100, 25 >>> (&count);
```

Should be

```
inc <<< 100, 25 >>> (count);
```