# CUDA atomicAdd() with long long int

Tags: cuda, int, addition, atomic, long-integer

Any time I try to use `atomicAdd` with anything other than `(*int, int)` I get this error:

```
error: no instance of overloaded function "atomicAdd" matches the argument list
```

But I need to use a larger data type than `int`. Is there any workaround here?

Device Query:

```
/usr/local/cuda/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery/deviceQuery Starting...

 CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GTX 680"
  CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          5.0 / 5.0
  CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    3.0
  Total amount of global memory:                 4095 MBytes (4294246400 bytes)
  ( 8) Multiprocessors x (192) CUDA Cores/MP:    1536 CUDA Cores
  GPU Clock rate:                                1084 MHz (1.08 GHz)
  Memory Clock rate:                             3004 Mhz
  Memory Bus Width:                              256-bit
  L2 Cache Size:                                 524288 bytes
  Max Texture Dimension Size (x,y,z)             1D=(65536), 2D=(65536,65536), 3D=(4096,4096,4096)
  Max Layered Texture Size (dim) x layers        1D=(16384) x 2048, 2D=(16384,16384) x 2048
  Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes
  Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes
  Total number of registers available per block: 65536
  Warp size:                                     32
  Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048
  Maximum number of threads per block:           1024
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a block:    1024 x 1024 x 64
  Maximum sizes of each dimension of a grid:     2147483647 x 65535 x 65535
  Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
  Texture alignment:                             512 bytes
  Concurrent copy and kernel execution:          Yes with 1 copy engine(s)
  Run time limit on kernels:                     Yes
  Integrated GPU sharing Host Memory:            No
  Support host page-locked memory mapping:       Yes
  Alignment requirement for Surfaces:            Yes
  Device has ECC support:                        Disabled
  Device supports Unified Addressing (UVA):      Yes
  Device PCI Bus ID / PCI location ID:           1 / 0
  Compute Mode:
     < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 5.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 5.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = GeForce GTX 680
```

Comment: Can you work with `unsigned long long int` or does it have to be `long long int`?  If you can use the unsigned version, it should work.  If you must use the signed 64 bit version, you can make a variant of the example given in [the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#arithmetic-functions) for arbitrary atomic access using atomicCAS.  If you need help with that, respond accordingly and I can give you an example.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is wrong compile flags. You're looking for anything other than int, you should be using sm_12 or higher.

As stated by Robert Crovella the `unsigned long long int` variable is supported, but the `long long int` is not.

Used the code from: [Beginner CUDA - Simple var increment not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408710/beginner-cuda-simple-var-increment-not-working)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

__global__ void inc(unsigned long long int *foo) {
  atomicAdd(foo, 1);
}

int main() {
  unsigned long long int count = 0, *cuda_count;
  cudaMalloc((void**)&cuda_count, sizeof(unsigned long long int));
  cudaMemcpy(cuda_count, &count, sizeof(unsigned long long int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cout << "count: " << count << '\n';
  inc <<< 100, 25 >>> (cuda_count);
  cudaMemcpy(&count, cuda_count, sizeof(unsigned long long int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaFree(cuda_count);
  cout << "count: " << count << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled from Linux: `nvcc -gencode arch=compute_12,code=sm_12 -o add add.cu`

Result:

```
count: 0
count: 2500
```

Comment: Why does `unsigned long long int` appear as an overload for `atomicAdd()` in the documentation but not `unsigned long int`?

Comment: @Adam27X My guess is that on the NVidia architecture, the size of a `long` and the size of an `int` are the same, but the `long long int` is larger.